# Edit keyframes on geometry nodes

Tags: edit-mode, keyframes, geometry-nodes

I set keyframes on the min and max value of an "Attribute Randomize" node. Now I want to move those keyframes but I don't see them in either of the keyframe editing modes (Dop Sheet, Timeline, Graph Editor).

Is that intentional, a bug, or am a missing something?

This is in v2.93.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Disable "Only show selected" on your graph editor and they will show up:

[image]

Unfortunately, everything else will show up too.

My recommendation for nearly any non-standard, per-object animated values, is to drive them from a bone rather than animate them directly.  This gives you a single place to store all animated values for a single object on something discrete and easily selected, and it vastly simplifies the coordination of animated values when using NLA.

Comment: Thanks! But nope. The geometry node does not even show up in the list.

I must be doing something wrong. A few days back I was putting noise on the values and saw the curves...

Comment: How can I add a screenshot to a comment?!?

Comment: @ alFrame You may have some other filters enabled in your graph editor that prevent them from showing up.  Or, you may be editing a different action.  I don't think I could give an exhaustive list of reasons why something doesn't show up, not without looking at a file.  As for screenshots, just edit the question-- there's no reason not to include as much information as possible, including things already tried.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! Your tip to look into filtering  solved it. I had modifiers turned off. DOH...

I checked the view menu, disabled "show selected only", selected the geometry node in the outliner, all that sitting and in a hand stand. Nothing helped. But now it's all good!!

How do I select an answer? Answering my own question gave me negative points the other day.

Comment: @alFrame I don't remember, it's been a long time since I asked any questions :)  But I wouldn't stress it (or points) too much if I were in your shoes.  The ultimate issue here is you had some filters enabled that you didn't mention in the question, so it's not a great candidate for a top Google hit for anyone anyways.

Comment: Well, I could not mention it because I obviously missed it. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @alFrame Yeah, I didn't mean to make you feel bad or anything.  I understand.  I'm just saying, there are basically 2 purposes to SE questions: 1) solve the questioner's problem; 2) help future researchers.  In this case, 1 is done, so great; and 2 is not going to happen, because of the nature of the problem.  So since everything good that can happen, has happened, I don't see any reason to dot all the i's.

Answer (score 1):

at least i have a workaround for you:

Just plug the min/max to your "Group input"-node and then you can keyframe then on the modifier panel (in the picture on the right side where the yellow color is) and this you can see and modify in the graph editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I found this approach on the interwebs as well. But rigging x,y and z min/max of 3 animated nodes just to be able to manipulate the keyframes is reeeeeal tedious.

Comment: No hard feelings